# How to implement a generic First "case/switch" type

Tags: typescript, types

I am currently in the process of refactoring the typings of redux-starter-kit to be more readable for non-typescript-powerusers.

Right now, it looks like this:

```js
 type PayloadActionCreator<
  P = any,
  T extends string = string,
  PA extends PrepareAction<P> | void = void
  > =
  IfPrepareActionMethodProvided<PA,
    ActionCreatorWithPreparedPayload<PA, T>,
    IfMaybeUndefined<P,
      ActionCreatorWithOptionalPayload<P, T>,
      IfVoid<P,
        ActionCreatorWithoutPayload<T>,
        ActionCreatorWithPayload<P, T>
      >
    >
  >
```

but I want to do away with the nesting and hope to achieve something like this:

```js
type PayloadActionCreator<
  P = any,
  T extends string = string,
  PA extends PrepareAction<P> | void = void
  > =
  First<
    IfPrepareActionMethodProvided<PA, ActionCreatorWithPreparedPayload<PA, T>, void>,
    IfMaybeUndefined<P, ActionCreatorWithOptionalPayload<P, T>, void>,
    IfVoid<P, ActionCreatorWithoutPayload<T>, void>,
    ActionCreatorWithPayload<P, T>
  >;
```

So, `First` should be a type that takes a number of types and returns the fist of them that is not `void`

I've implemented a naive version of `First` that works quite well, until a type with a generic like `IfVoid` is passed into it. Then I get to the case, where I get `void` returned, even if there would be later options given that are not `void` - see this code:

```js
type FallbackIfNotVoid<Type,  False> = [Type] extends [void] ? False : Type;

type First<
  A = void,
  B = void,
  C = void,
  D = void
  > = 
  FallbackIfNotVoid<A, 
  FallbackIfNotVoid<B, 
  FallbackIfNotVoid<C, 
  FallbackIfNotVoid<D, void>
  >>>;


  type IfVoid<P, True, False = void> = [void] extends [P] ? True : False;

  type Experiment<T> = First<
    IfVoid<T, "voidCase">,
    T
  >;

  type VoidType = Experiment<void>; // "voidCase", as expected
  type OtherType = Experiment<"test"> // this should be "test", but is void
```

I'm guessing this is something with TS doing some pre-optimization that backfires later. 
Hovering the type indicates that my type definition is optimized to `[void] extends [T] ? "voidCase" : void`

Does someone have an idea on how to implement such a `First` type alternatively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typescript bug.

First the workaround, if we take `void` out of the conditional types and put it into the type parameters to the type alias:

```
type FallbackIfNotVoid<Default, Type, False> = [Type] extends [Default] ? False : Type;

type First<
  Default = void,
  A = void,
  B = void,
  C = void,
  D = void> =
  FallbackIfNotVoid<Default, A,
  FallbackIfNotVoid<Default, B,
  FallbackIfNotVoid<Default, C,
  FallbackIfNotVoid<Default, D, Default>>>>;


type IfVoid<P, True, False = void> = [void] extends [P] ? True : False;

type Experiment<T, Default = void> = First<Default,
  IfVoid<T, "voidCase">,
  T
>;

type VoidType = Experiment<void>; // "voidCase", as expected
type OtherType = Experiment<"test"> // "test" now
```

Now for the bug, this is a minimal reproduction:

```
type Default = { x: string }

type M<A> = [A extends "A" ? A : Default] extends [Default] ? "Y" : "N" // Simplified to "Y" regardless of A
```

`M` is simplified to `"Y"`. This happens if the tested type (`[A extends "A" ? A : Default]`) is also a conditional type and if that conditional type contains in the false branch the type that is tested for in the outer conditional type. This only happens for the false branch. For example the type below does not get similarly simplified:

```
type Default = { x: string }

type M<A> = [A extends "A" ? Default: A] extends [Default] ? "Y" : "N" // no simplification
```

Putting the `Default` in a type parameter works around this because it prevents this eager optimization.

I will search for an existing issue and post it if I find it. I am 100% sure I have seen similar issues relating to conditional type simplification, just not sure if they were this exact one.

**Edit**: Yup I was right, I did see something similar before, was even involved in the conversation about it (getting forgetful in my old age ) [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30708) is the issue, jack-williams has a similar repro there as well:

```
type Inner<T> = [T] extends [true] ? false : true;
type Outer<T> = [Inner<T>] extends [true] ? 1 : 2; // Already resolved to 2.
```